# Excel VBA script Seperate sheet by large change

Tags: vba, excel

Background: I've been working with VBA scripts recently in Excel. My RC radio generates log files only for every day. So I may have three sessions in the same spreadsheet. The way to tell the start of one session and the beginning of another is by looking at the "Time of Day" Column where increments are generally less than a second

I have found that you can separate data to separate sheets using VBA scripts.

**Is it possible to have Excel read through a column and perform an action if the change from the previous value is more than a few seconds?**

```
Time of Day  Rudder ...
15:33:08.5   -1
15:33:08.7   ...
15:33:08.9
15:33:09.2
16:31:45.3 <
16:31:45.5
16:31:45.8
16:31:46.0
16:31:46.2
```

In the above data sample I would like VBA to split at the row I have marked because the delta from the row above is greater than 10 seconds.

EDIT: I ran the code on one of my spreadsheets after selecting the time column I wanted analyzed. It worked for this:

```
15:33:08.720
15:33:08.940
15:33:09.150
16:31:45.320  Changes
16:31:45.530
```

But It also showed a change here:

```
16:31:58.780    
16:31:59.000    
16:31:59.200    
16:31:59.420    
16:31:59.620    Changes
16:31:59.840    
16:32:00.040
```

It's weird because in other places the change is .2 seconds but it is not marked as a change!

Answer (score 0):

Run this code

```
Sub testing()
    Dim erange As Range



For Each erange In Selection

    va = Split(erange.Text, ":")
    va2 = Split(erange.Offset(1, 0).Text, ":")

    If va(1) <> va2(1) Then

    erange.Offset(1, 1).Value = "Changes"

    End If

    Next erange
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @user3114645. It works for some changes but not for all. How do I alter the change the code is looking for? I've edited my question to show where your code seems to get a little confused.